# How do I deserialize this json text in c# and class name cannot be a number

Tags: c#

```
public class Image
{
    public string id_image { get; set; }
    public string id_product_attribute { get; set; }
    public string legend { get; set; }
}

public class AllImages
{
    public List<Image> Images { get; set; }
}

string jsonData = {"6983122":[{"id_image":"153553","id_product_attribute":"6983122","legend":""},{"id_image":"153554","id_product_attribute":"6983122","legend":""},{"id_image":"153555","id_product_attribute":"6983122","legend":""},{"id_image":"156089","id_product_attribute":"6983122","legend":""},{"id_image":"153556","id_product_attribute":"6983122","legend":""},{"id_image":"153557","id_product_attribute":"6983122","legend":""}],"6983123":[{"id_image":"153553","id_product_attribute":"6983123","legend":""},{"id_image":"153554","id_product_attribute":"6983123","legend":""},{"id_image":"153555","id_product_attribute":"6983123","legend":""},{"id_image":"156089","id_product_attribute":"6983123","legend":""},{"id_image":"153556","id_product_attribute":"6983123","legend":""},{"id_image":"153557","id_product_attribute":"6983123","legend":""}],"6983124":[{"id_image":"153553","id_product_attribute":"6983124","legend":""},{"id_image":"153554","id_product_attribute":"6983124","legend":""},{"id_image":"153555","id_product_attribute":"6983124","legend":""},{"id_image":"156089","id_product_attribute":"6983124","legend":""},{"id_image":"153556","id_product_attribute":"6983124","legend":""},{"id_image":"153557","id_product_attribute":"6983124","legend":""}],"6983125":[{"id_image":"153553","id_product_attribute":"6983125","legend":""},{"id_image":"153554","id_product_attribute":"6983125","legend":""},{"id_image":"153555","id_product_attribute":"6983125","legend":""},{"id_image":"156089","id_product_attribute":"6983125","legend":""},{"id_image":"153556","id_product_attribute":"6983125","legend":""},{"id_image":"153557","id_product_attribute":"6983125","legend":""}],"6983126":[{"id_image":"153553","id_product_attribute":"6983126","legend":""},{"id_image":"153554","id_product_attribute":"6983126","legend":""},{"id_image":"153555","id_product_attribute":"6983126","legend":""},{"id_image":"156089","id_product_attribute":"6983126","legend":""},{"id_image":"153556","id_product_attribute":"6983126","legend":""},{"id_image":"153557","id_product_attribute":"6983126","legend":""}],"6983760":[{"id_image":"153553","id_product_attribute":"6983760","legend":""},{"id_image":"153554","id_product_attribute":"6983760","legend":""},{"id_image":"153555","id_product_attribute":"6983760","legend":""},{"id_image":"156089","id_product_attribute":"6983760","legend":""},{"id_image":"153556","id_product_attribute":"6983760","legend":""},{"id_image":"153557","id_product_attribute":"6983760","legend":""}]};

string json = "["+jsonData+"]";
List<AllImages> images = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AllImages>>(json);
```

I want to read this json data, but the numbers at the beginning of json make my job difficult, since these numbers are constantly changing, how can I write and deserilize a class that will cover all the numbers?

How can I deserialize this type of data without tampering with string manipulations?

Comment: Try `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Image[]>>()`

Comment: Yes, it works now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

first you should deserialize it to a specific dictionary and then select the values.

```
Dictionary<string, List<AllImages>> dic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<AllImages>>>(json);
```

then:

```
var images = dic.First().Value;
```